# evosuite _ESTest.java results reported in sonar/jacoco

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, evosuite

We have a single evosuite generated unittest .java file. We have other hand-crafted unittest .java files. We execute a build on our server and all unittests (evosuite and hand-crafted) are executed. We then go into our sonar dashboard and specifically look at the coverage. There is coverage reported by sonar/jacoco from the handcrafted unittests. However for the .java file that the evosuite was to test, that file still has 0% coverage even though on another panel in the sonar/jacoco dashboard the evosuite 16 tests were executed and it shows how long in ms they took.

The server where the builds take place was configured for us and we do not manage them. Sonar/Jacoco admin setup was done by others.

I'm at a loss as to why our handcrafted ones (some use @RunWith(JMockit.class) and some don't use a RunWith annotation) show up w/ coverage percentages and the evosuite does not.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is an issue that has been reported few times now... so I just added now some documentation about it :-) at:

http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/measuring-code-coverage/

you can read there why you get 0% coverage, and possible workarounds for it.